# ionic 3 - Position retrieval timed out only for iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, mobile, permissions, geolocation

It works perfect on the browser and on Android (device and emulator), but when it comes to iOS, it does **NEVER** ask for Location permission and I get a timeout error when I try to get the user's position.

I'm completely lost, I installed AndroidPermissions just to check if I do have the permission, and it turns out I do (don't know how since the prompt to give the app permission to access the location NEVER showed up).

I am using

```
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^3.0.0",
"cordova-ios": "^4.5.4"
```

And the code looks something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
@Injectable()
export class BaresProvider {

    getPosition() {
        return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({ timeout: 15000 });
    }
}
```

Again, I consume this service from another class and on Android it works just as expected.

Please some input!

Answer (score 2):

So, I've just solved it by adding these two keys with a string in my app's info.plist file:

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription